# I would like to increase the description width of this acronyms list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, width

```
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{Glosario}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % remove trailing dot
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=longheaderborder,title=,nonumberlist]
\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a MWE that compiles.

Comment: You only have to create a Glosario.tex where you add \newacronym{RES}{RES}{Renewable Energy Sources} and it will compile. That is why I am using the command \input{glosario}.